# Reversing a list of objects with a timespan property, while maintaining the time difference between the objects

Tags: c#, list

I'd like to reverse a list of objects with a TimeSpan property, which should maintain it's TimeSpan difference when reversing.

To give an example, consider a route from A to D with the following TimeSpans:
**(A 12:00), (B 12:15), (C 12:40), (D 13:40)**.

Between A and B there is a 15 minute difference, between B and C there is a 25 minute difference and so on. I'd like to reverse this list in an efficient manner, where the result list would look like:
**(D: 12:00), (C 13:00), (B 13:25), (A 13:40)**.

My first idea was creating a list of time differences and using that and the start time to create the new objects with the correct times, however I feel like the solution could be better.

Edit: Added my (working) sample solution. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
        private IList<Activity> ReverseActivities(IList<Activity> activities)
        {
            IList<TimeSpan> timeDifferences = GetTimeDifferences(activities);
            IList<Activity> resultList = new List<Activity>();

            TimeSpan timeOfDay = activities.First().TimeOfDay;

            for (int i = activities.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {            
                resultList.Add(new Activity(activities[i].Name, timeOfDay));
                timeOfDay = timeOfDay.Add(timeDifferences[i]);
            }

            return resultList;
        }

        private IList<TimeSpan> GetTimeDifferences(IList<Activity> activities)
        {
            IList<TimeSpan> timeDifferences = new List<TimeSpan>();
            Activity prev = activities.First();

            if (activities.Count > 1)
            {
                foreach (var curr in activities)
                {
                    timeDifferences.Add(curr.TimeOfDay - prev.TimeOfDay);
                    prev = curr;
                }
            }

            return timeDifferences;
        }
```

Activity looks as follows:

```
public class Activity
    {
        public Activity(string name, TimeSpan timeOfDay)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.TimeOfDay = timeOfDay;
        }

        public string Name { get; }

        public TimeSpan TimeOfDay { get; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your attempt? Maybe you were on the right track. Also would be helpful to know the actual types of the objects in question. Try to provide a minimum viable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Surely you could take the time to produce a `List<TimeSpan>` that contains some values, and then show the expected result? Can you show the attempt you've made so we can see where it's not working?

Comment: Also "reverse a list of objects" seems like your attempt to solve another problem, talk us about the problem too, not just how to acomplish your attempt to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure those are `TimeSpan` properties and not `DateTime` properties? Typically `TimeSpan` is a difference between two `DateTime` objects, and stops along a route would have a `TimeOfDeparture` (or similar) property that represents a `Time`, not a `TimeSpan`

Comment: Im working out my solution in an example. Or atleast two examples of solutions, which I considered. I'm currently stuck with TimeSpan properties and not DateTime however.

Comment: @RufusL I posted my working example.

Comment: @RufusL I liked the solution you posted, but deleted. I'd like to accept the answer you gave as I think it's definitely a cleaner solution than my example.

Comment: Since your code is fully working, but may or may not require some improvement, I'd suggest you use [Code review stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of SO.

Comment: I just deleted it while modifying it for your sample class, it's undeleted now. But I have to say, Enigmativity's answer is so much more elegant! I wish my brain worked like that (or at least as fast as that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple using a bit of `TimeSpan` maths.

```
IList<Activity> input = new List<Activity>()
{
    new Activity("A", TimeSpan.Parse("12:00")),
    new Activity("B", TimeSpan.Parse("12:15")),
    new Activity("C", TimeSpan.Parse("12:40")),
    new Activity("D", TimeSpan.Parse("13:40")),
};

TimeSpan min = input.Min(x => x.TimeOfDay);
TimeSpan max = input.Max(x => x.TimeOfDay);

IList<Activity> output =
    input
        .Select(x => new Activity(
            x.Name,
            x.TimeOfDay.Subtract(max).Duration().Add(min)))
        .OrderBy(x => x.TimeOfDay)
        .ToList();
```

That gives me:

[image: output]

Comment: I forgot to thank you for this solution. However I still have a question. How'd you go about doing this when min starts before midnight, i.e. 23:00 and ends the next day, i.e. 07:00. In those solutions, this would not work (neither would be own example).

Comment: Given the definition of your class `Activity` my code would work perfectly fine as `TimeSpan` is not limited to a 24 hour period. However, if you're getting the `TimeOfDay` from a `DateTime` `TimeOfDay` property then you would also need to get it relative to the date, not just the time of day. You'd need to post the full code for me to say more.

Answer (score 2):

One trick we can use is to have a single loop that finds the corresponding item from the end of the list based on the current index. We can do this like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < activities.Count; i++)
    var correspondingIndex = activities.Count - i - 1;
```

Notice that:

- When `i` is `0`, `correspondingIndex` is the last index in the array.
- When `i` is `1`, `correspondingIndex` is the second-to-last index in the array.
- When `i` is `activities.Count - 1` (the last index), `correspondingIndex` is `0`

Using this trick, we can get the corresponding time differences at the same time as we populate a new list of `Activity` objects.

Hopefully this code makes it a little clearer:

```
public static IList<Activity> ReverseActivities(IList<Activity> activities)
{
    // If activities is null or contains less than 2 items, return it
    if ((activities?.Count ?? 0) < 2) return activities;

    // This will contain the reversed list
    var reversed = new List<Activity>();

    for (int i = 0; i < activities.Count; i++)
    {
        // Get the corresponding index from the end of the list
        var correspondingIndex = activities.Count - i - 1;

        // Get the timespan from the corresponding items from the end of the list
        var timeSpan = i == 0
            ? TimeSpan.Zero
            : activities[correspondingIndex + 1].TimeOfDay -
                activities[correspondingIndex].TimeOfDay;

        // The new TimeOfDay will be the previous item's TimeOfDay plus the TimeSpan above
        var timeOfDay = i == 0
            ? activities[i].TimeOfDay
            : reversed[i - 1].TimeOfDay + timeSpan;

        reversed.Add(new Activity(activities[correspondingIndex].Name, timeOfDay));
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

In use, this would look like:

```
var original = new List<Activity>
{
    new Activity("A", new TimeSpan(0, 12, 0)),
    new Activity("B", new TimeSpan(0, 12, 15)),
    new Activity("C", new TimeSpan(0, 12, 40)),
    new Activity("D", new TimeSpan(0, 13, 40))
};

var reversed = ReverseActivities(original);
```

Here's the output in the debug window (compare `original` and `reversed`):

[image]

Comment: That's a nice line: `if ((activities?.Count ?? 0) < 2) return activities;`. Handling the null case and count to low case in one concise line.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it works:

```
DateTime[] times = { new DateTime(2020, 06, 17, 12, 00, 00),
    new DateTime(2020, 06, 17, 12, 15, 00), new DateTime(2020, 06, 17, 12, 40, 00),
    new DateTime(2020, 06, 17, 13, 40, 00) };

List<DateTime> newTimes = new List<DateTime>();
newTimes.Add(times[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < times.Length; i++) {
    DateTime d = newTimes[i - 1].Add(times[times.Length - i] - times[times.Length - i - 1]);
    newTimes.Add(d);
}
```

Comment: FYI, I don't think you're wrong, but those are not objects with a `TimeSpan` property...

Comment: @RufusL ok then just make a list of the objects and add them like this `newTimes.Add(new YourObject().TimeSpanProperty...`. I gave OP the algorithm, I haven't even seen any code, it's up to him to adapt my code to fit his code.

Answer (score 0):

Using LinkedList:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Location>
        {
            new Location{Name = "A", TimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0)) },
            new Location{Name = "B", TimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(12, 15, 0)) },
            new Location{Name = "C", TimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(12, 40, 0)) },
            new Location{Name = "D", TimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(13, 40, 0)) },
        };

        var route = new LinkedList<Location>(list);

        WriteToConsole("Before: ", route);
        var reversedRoute = Reverse(route);
        Console.WriteLine();
        WriteToConsole("After: ", reversedRoute);

        Console.WriteLine(); Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static LinkedList<Location> Reverse(LinkedList<Location> route)
    {
        LinkedList<Location> retVal = new LinkedList<Location>();

        DateTimeOffset timeOffset = DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
        var currentNode = route.Last;
        while (currentNode != null)
        {
            var next = currentNode.Next;
            if (next == null)
            {
                // last node, use the first node offset
                timeOffset = DateTimeOffset.MinValue.Add(route.First.Value.TimeOffset - timeOffset);
            }
            else
            {
                timeOffset = timeOffset.Add(next.Value.TimeOffset - currentNode.Value.TimeOffset);
            }

            retVal.AddLast(new Location { Name = currentNode.Value.Name, TimeOffset = timeOffset });
            currentNode = currentNode.Previous;
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public static void WriteToConsole(string title, LinkedList<Location> route)
    {
        Console.Write($"{title}: ");
        foreach (var i in route)
        {
            Console.Write($"\t({i.Name}, {i.TimeOffset.Hour:D2}:{i.TimeOffset.Minute:D2})");
        }
    }
```